# Using Animated Value in React Native Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to write a react native component in typescript that has a Animated.View from the Animated API in the render function.

I'm having an issue setting the Animated.Value as a property of the React Component.

My current code is as follows:

```
interface NotificationProps {
animation : Animated.Value
...
}

class Notification extends React.Component <NotificationProps,NotificationState> {
  constructor (props: NotificationProps) {
      super(props)
      this.props.animation = new Animated.Value(0)
      ...
      this.state = {...}
```

However, the ts linter produces the error:

> Cannot assign to 'animation' because it is a read-only property

In javascript, simply declaring the Animated.Value in the constructor as below works fine:

```
this.animation = new Animated.Value(0)
```

I'm using react native v. 0.61.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having has nothing to do with the fact you are using TypeScript.

The issue is you are trying to assign value to a prop which is a read-only variable type.

You can find more about this in the react official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#:%7E:text=Props%20are%20Read%2DOnly&text=Such%20functions%20are%20called%20%E2%80%9Cpure,result%20for%20the%20same%20inputs.&text=React%20is%20pretty%20flexible%20but,with%20respect%20to%20their%20props.).

There is no logic in assign value to a prop in the constructor as the prop purpuse is to get a value from the parent.

What you should do insted is to declare 'animation' as a state value instead. You will have no problem to declare it and assign a value to it.

```
this.state = {
   animation: new Animated.Value(0),
   ...
}
```